# How to show reports in Arabic Language in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to Develop APEX application but Arabic Letters doesn't support.
I have selected the Globalization attribute in Arabic but that was not useful.
The Arabic text appears like this:ÏæäÇáÏ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to Arabic fonts in ords and apex pdf print template,
the solution is here:

https://damir-vadas.blogspot.com/2014/07/apex-listener-prints-instead-of.html

Note that you can not Download PDF with Embedded Pl/SQL Gateway (EPG), you need ORDS (Apex Listener).

Answer (score 2):

As far as support for Arabic in APEX goes checkout the site http://translate-apex.com - you'll find there multiple translations of APEX internal messages, including one for Arabic. You also need to make sure that the rest of your setup (database encoding, NLS params, web server / ords setup, etc.) is OK as far as Arabic letters are concerned.